# Is there an accepted architecture for these classes?

Tags: architecture, software-engineering, design-patterns

I am coding a game in python and so far so good, but I feel like my classes are not very modular. This is a simplification of what I've done:

```
class Game:
def __init__(self):
    self.characters = []
    self.walls = []
    self.background = None
    self.canvas = None
    self.keyInputs = None

def update(self, inputs):
    self.keyInputs = inputs
    for character in self.characters:
        if character.died:
            self.characters.remove(character)
        else:
            character.update()

def draw(self):
    self.background.draw()
    for wall in self.walls:
        wall.draw()
    for character in self.characters:
        character.draw()

class Character:
    def __init__(self):
        self.horizontalPosition = 0
        self.verticalPosition = 0
        self.game = None
        self.died = False
        self.sprite = None
        ...

    def draw(self):
        self.game.canvas.draw(self.sprite, self.horizontalPosition, self.verticalPosition)

    def interactWith(self, character):
        ...

    def detectCollition(self, wall):
        ...

    def handleInputs(self):
        inputs = self.game.keyInputs
        ...

    def update(self):
        self.handleInputs()
        for character in self.game.characters:
            if character != self:
                self.interactWith(character)
        for wall in self.game.walls:
            self.detectCollition(wall)
```

This way Characters and Walls need to have a variable for which Game they are in, and a Game needs to have a variable for each Character or Wall that is in it.

Is there a better way to define these classes? Are there design patterns for this?

Comment: *Why* do walls and characters need to know the game they are in?

Comment: @Philipp To know what other characters and walls they may interact with (for example in collision detection) and to be able to have their own draw function they need to know on which canvas to draw themselves in.

Comment: You could also have those things handled from the outside or pass the necessary data into the methods which do these things.

Comment: Do you think passing the necessary data into the methods is a better aproach?

Comment: It is *one* approach. There is never a *best* solution in software development. Only the best solution for your project.

Comment: Hey, welcome to [gamedev.se]! Unfortunately, the "global improvements" you're asking here are too open ended for the scope of _this site_. "Better" in what way? Our focus is more on fixing issues, and as stated now, there are no issues that are presented. If the code works for you and for your game, that's all that matters. If you think there is an issue with it, then please edit the question and highlight what you need us to help you fix. If it's edited in an answerable form, as per the standards of the site, we'll be happy to reopen it :)